# ServiceController Required Privileges

Tags: .net, privileges, servicecontroller

I'm using a ServiceController to Start services on a remote machine. When I want to query the services on that machine, I get the following exception:

Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'machinename'. This operation might require other privileges.

What privileges are required to query/start/stop the services on a remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Administrator

Comment: Local Administrator?  Domain Administrator?